# Strange result, when changing variable name

Tags: shaders, glsl

I have no idea, what is going on. The mat4 xxx is the cause. Renaming it to "bones"/"bone_transfromations" etc. won't work it gives me an error. Renaming it to "test" works perfectly fine... This is my GLSL code:

```
#version 400 core

//data from VBO
in vec3 position;
in vec2 texture_coordinates;
in vec3 normal;
//bone data
in int bone_pointer;
in float bone_intensity;
//vertex color output
out vec4 color;
//texture coordinates
out vec2 pass_texcoords;
out vec2 texCoord0;
//normal
out vec3 surface_normal;
//vector pointing towards the light
out vec3 to_light_vector;

//position, rotation, scale
uniform mat4 transformationMatrix;
//perspective projection
uniform mat4 projectionMatrix;
//TODO: material color
uniform vec3 in_color;
//camera viewmatrix
uniform mat4 viewMatrix;
//lights
uniform vec3 lightPosition;
uniform vec3 lightColor;
//skeleton data
uniform mat4 xxx;


void main()
{
mat4 total_transform = xxx * transformationMatrix;
vec4 worldPosition;

worldPosition =  total_transform * (vec4(position, 1)) ; // 

vec4 pos =  projectionMatrix * viewMatrix * worldPosition;
gl_Position = pos;

//Texture
pass_texcoords = texture_coordinates;

//light
surface_normal = (total_transform *  vec4(normal, 0)).xyz;
to_light_vector = lightPosition * worldPosition.xyz; 

//textures
 texCoord0 = texture_coordinates;

}
```

Comment: Have you got any other variables in your project named bones"/"bone_transfromations?

Comment: You've probably got duplicate variables somewhere. What does the error say?

Comment: Exception in thread "main" org.lwjgl.opengl.OpenGLException: Invalid operation (1282)
 at org.lwjgl.opengl.Util.checkGLError(Util.java:59)
 at org.lwjgl.opengl.GL20.glUniform3f(GL20.java:356)
 at game.engine.graphics.shaders.ShaderProgram.loadVector(ShaderProgram.java:49)
 at game.engine.graphics.shaders.EntityShader.loadLight(EntityShader.java:94)
 at game.engine.graphics.shaders.material.Material.bind(Material.java:42)
No, there are no dublicates, I can't even name it bones_8314 or testx, I have no Idea...I'm confused...

Comment: You may be running into some problems with their shader translation, a wild guess is a misinterpretation as a swizzle.